# How to track/preserve global namespace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, global-namespace, window-object

I was wondering what would be the best way to track changes made to the global namespace by some external javascripts. For example, lets say I have a website and I would like to know which object are being added to the global namespace by some third party software that is running on a visitor's machine.
Also is there a way to preserve global namespace from these changes ?

Comment: What do you mean by "preserve" ?

Comment: By "preserve" I meant how to protect global namespace, maybe prevent adding objects to it and so.

Answer (score 0):

ES5 has [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) for 'preserving' objects:

```
Object.freeze(window);
Object.freeze(Object);
Object.freeze(Object.prototype);
```

Etc.

ES6's proxy API will allow you to track changes to objects, but the specification is still being drafted. SpiderMonkey has a [prototype implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).